# Properties of equivalence relation

Tags: equivalence-relations

**(a)** Property $2$ of an equivalence relation states that if $a\sim b$ then $b\sim a$. property $3$ states that if $a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$ then $a\sim c$. What is wrong with the following proof that properties $2$ and $3$ imply property $1$? Let $a\sim b$; then $b\sim a$, whence, by property $3$ (using $a=c$), $a\sim a$.

**(b)** Can you suggest an alternative of property $1$ which will insure us that properties $2$ and $3$ do imply property $1$?

**My solution:** Let $X=\{0,1,2\}$. Let's consider relation $$R=\{(0,1),(1,0),(0,2),(2,0),(1,2),(2,1)\}\subset X\times X$$ We can check that this relation is symmetric and transitive. Since $(0,1)\in R$ and $(1,0)\in R$ then $(0,0)\in R$. However, we see that it is not true. What is the problem? Can anyone explain it in detail?

Comment: For a given $a$, neither property 2 nor property 3 guarantees that there is any $b$ such that $a\sim b$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I cannot understand. I was interesting why for relation $R$ reflexivity does not hold.

Comment: Let $R$ a symmetric and transitive relation on $X$. Let $Y = \{ x \in X : (\exists y)(x R y)\}$. Then $R$ is an equivalence relation on $Y$, but it can be that $Y \subsetneqq X$. And then, $R$ is not an equivalence relation on $X$.

Comment: Is my $R$ symmetric and transitive?

Comment: It's not transitive, you have $(0,1) \in R$ and $(1,0) \in R$, but not $(0,0) \in R$.

Comment: Mm yes! Thanks a lot. But What is wrong with the above argument in proof?

Comment: You start with "Let $a\sim b$", but such a $b$ need not exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68095/discussion-between-rfz-and-daniel-fischer).

Comment: @DanielFischer, could you take a look at that problem? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2512308/0-1-cannot-be-partititioned-into-two-sets-with-given-properties

Answer (score 0):

The issue is property (2) states that for all $a,b \in X$ we have that $a\sim b$ if and only if $b \sim a$. This is $\textit{not}$ saying that $a \sim b$ and $b \sim a$ for all $a,b \in X$.

So, if you were to let $b = a$. Property (2) simply implies that $a \sim a$ if and only if $a \sim a$, a statement that is true regardless of whether or not $a$ really is related to $a$.  And property (3) does nothing to help us out of this predicament.