# $[0,1]$ cannot be partititioned into two sets with given properties

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that the interval $[0,1]$ cannot be partitioned into two disjoint sets $A$ and $B$ such that $B=A+a$ for some real number $a$.

**My proof:** Suppose by contradiction that $[0,1]=A\sqcup B$ where $B=A+a$ and WLOG let $a>0$. It's easy to verify that $0\in A$ and $1-a\in A$. Also it's easy to prove that $A\subset [0,1-a]$ and $B=A+a\subset [a,1]$.

*First case:* If $1-a<a$ then $a>\frac{1}{2}$. It is easy to show that in this case $\frac{1}{2}\notin [0,1-a]$ and $\frac{1}{2}\notin [a,1]$ $\Rightarrow$ $1/2\notin A$ and $1/2\notin B$ but $1/2\in [0,1]$. This is a contradiction.

*Second case:* If $1-a=a$ then $a=\frac{1}{2}$. In this case $A\subset [0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and $B\subset [\frac{1}{2},1]$. Since $0\in A$ then $\frac{1}{2}\in B$. Since $1\in B$ then $1-\frac{1}{2}\in A$. Thus $\frac{1}{2}\in A\cap B$. Contradiction.

*Third case:* If $1-a>a$ then $a<\frac{1}{2}$. Let $I=[a,1-a]$ and it can be shown that $I\cap A\neq \varnothing$ and $I\cap B\neq \varnothing$. I have stuck here and not able to derive contradiction.

Can anyone please give a hint how to overcome this obstacle?

Comment: Let this be pointed out: solving just the third part is no easier than solving the whole task. Considering the first two cases is rather useless.

Answer (score 4):

(Just working around the points $0$ and $1$ is not sufficient. We have to cross the abyss in between in a controlled way.)

We go ahead and  find out how two such sets would have to look like. We therefore assume that $A$ and $B$ form such a partition of $[0,1]$, whereby $0<a<1$. Then necessarily $[0,a[\>\subset A$, hence $[a,2a[\>\subset B$. Therefore the points in $[2a,3a[\>$ have to lie in $A$, and so forth. It turns out that the half open intervals
$$[0,a[\>,\quad [2a,3a[\>,\quad [4a,5a[\>,\quad\ldots$$ (up to the upper limit $1$) all belong to $A$ and the intervals
$$[a,2a[\>,\quad [3a,4a[\>,\quad [5a,6a[\>,\quad\ldots$$ (up to the upper limit $1$) all belong to $B$. The number $1$ necessarily belongs to one of the $B$-intervals. Therefore we have
$$(2m-1)a\leq 1<2m a$$
for some $m\geq1$. There is a $\beta$ with $1<\beta<2ma$. As $\beta$ is in the cutoff of a $B$-interval it follows that $\alpha:=\beta-a\in A$. But $\alpha+a>1$, hence $\alpha+a\notin B$. This violates the condition $B=A+a$.

Comment: Nice solution. But let me ask you one question: Indeed, $[0,a)\subset A$ hence $[a,2a)\subset B$. But how do you get that $[2a,3a)\subset A$. What  is some point of interval $[2a,3a)$ lies in $B$?

Comment: @RFZ Since $B = A+a$, if some $\beta \in [2a, 3a)$ lies in $B$, then $\beta - a \in [a, 2a)$ would lie in $A$, which it does not.

Comment: @Adayah, Also above he stated that $1\in B$. What about if $1\in A$ then $1+a\in B$ but $B\subset [0,1]$ and here we get contradiction since $a>0$, right?

Comment: ${}$${}$@RFZ Yeah.

Answer (score 3):

Fix $a \in (0,1)$ - those are the only options we need to consider - and define

$$x \sim_a y \iff \frac{x-y}{a} \in \mathbb{Z}.$$

Then we can partition $[0,1]$ in the specified way if and only we can partition each equivalence class of $\sim_a$ in the specified way. That means, if $\xi = \min \{ x \in [0,1] : x \sim_a \xi\}$, we must have $\xi + ka \in A$ for even $k$ with $\xi + ka \in [0,1]$ and $\xi + ka \in B$ for odd $k$. In particular, $k_{\max}(\xi) = \bigl\lfloor \frac{1-\xi}{a}\bigr\rfloor$ must be odd for every $\xi \in [0,a)$. Choosing $\xi = 0$ we see that there is an $n$ such that

$$\frac{1}{2n} < a \leqslant \frac{1}{2n-1}.$$

But $\bigl\lfloor \frac{1-\xi}{a}\bigr\rfloor$ is even (namely, it's $2n-2$) when

$$1 - (2n-1)a < \xi < a.$$

This is possible since $1 < 2na \implies 1-(2n-1)a < a$, and $(2n-1)a \leqslant 1 \implies a \leqslant 1 - (2n-2)a$ so we then have $\bigl\lfloor \frac{1-\xi}{a}\bigr\rfloor = 2n-2$ indeed.

So there always is an equivalence class that cannot be partitioned in the required way.

Comment: Thanks for post! Let me ask you one question I guess that there is no method for completing my third case?

Comment: I think there is. Similarly to what you have for $[0,1]$, you know that $A\cap [a,1-a] \subset [2a,1-a]$ and $B \cap [a,1-a] \subset [a,1-2a]$. You could then go on with the same sort of argument. But it may become complicated to keep track of the conditions imposed on $a$ and to show that in the end they lead to an impossibility. Fixing an arbitrary $a$ at the start and showing that that cannot work looks the easier way.

Comment: "Then we can partition $[0,1]$ in the specified way if and only we can partition each equivalence class of $\sim_a$ in the specified way." this sentence little bit unclear. Could you expand it please?

Comment: Also I cannot grasp the definition of $\xi$ and $k_{\text{max}}(\xi)$. The solution if quite hard :(

Comment: For $x \in [0,1]$ let $K(x) = \{ y \in [0,1] : x \sim_a y\}$. For an equivalence class $C$, let $A_C = A \cap C$ and $B_C = B\cap C$. If $A$ and $B$ partition $[0,1]$, then $A_C,B_C$ partition $C$. And if $B = A + a$ then $B_C = A_C + a$. Conversely, if for every equivalence class $C$ we have a partition of $C$ into $A_C$ and $B_C$ such that $B_C = A_C + a$, then $A = \bigcup_C A_C$ and $B = \bigcup_C B_C$ give a partition of $[0,1]$ with $B = A + a$. $\xi$ is just the smallest element of some equivalence class. The smallest element always belongs to $[0,a\mathclose[$, and each $\xi <a$ is the

Comment: …smallest element of its equivalence class. $k_{\max}(\xi)$ is just the largest integer such that $\xi + ka \leqslant 1$. Its parity tells us whether the largest element in the equivalence class of $\xi$ belongs to $A$ or to $B$.